# PostgreSQL not importing NULL values from a CSV file

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I created a huge database in `PostgreSQL` where I have integer fields that can take **NULL** values. However when I am trying to import data into the database from a **CSV** file, it throws me the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"
CONTEXT:  COPY reports_results, line 1, column teacher_id: "NULL"
```

I am trying to import into the database using the **copy** command like:

```
copy  reports_results(test_type_id, teacher_id)
from '/Downloads/mydata.csv';
```

So what I understood so far is that the database will not accept `NULL` values in quotes ie. `"NULL"`. But my **csv** file does not have any quotes wherever the `NULL` values are present. How do I import them in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your csv is something like:

```
1,NULL
2,NULL
```

Your command would be:

```
copy  reports_results(test_type_id, teacher_id)
from '/Downloads/mydata.csv';
with NULL as 'NULL'
```